# Multi associate array to single array using php

Tags: php

This is may array and i want to make a single array from it.

Following is my current array and i want array in single array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_name1] => First Name
            [quantity1] => 1
            [mc_gross1] => 189.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_name2] => Last Name
            [quantity2] => 1
            [mc_gross2] => 22.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_name3] => Email Addres
            [quantity3] => 3
            [mc_gross3] => 21.00
        )

)
```

ANd i Want like

```
 Array
(


    [item_name1] => First Name
    [quantity1] => 1
    [mc_gross1] => 189.00

    [item_name2] => Last Name
    [quantity2] => 1
    [mc_gross2] => 22.00


    [item_name3] => Email Addres
    [quantity3] => 3
    [mc_gross3] => 21.00


    )
```

I have tried by following way but i can not get result that i want.

```
<?php
$result = array();

foreach($result as $inner) {
       $result[key($inner)] = current($inner);    


}
?>
```

Someone please help me how could i resolve this ?

Comment: You can't have it like that. A key must be unique in an array. [mc_gross] and [quantity1] aren't unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below

```
<?php
$final_result = array();
foreach($result as $inner) {
   $final_result = array_merge($final_result,$inner);    
}
?>
```

Comment: I have changed key.

Comment: Great!! Thank You!!